# Strange crash when asking for location permission in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, crash, ios13

Device:

iPhone 8, iOS 13.1.3

Crash log from crashlytics:

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  XXXXXXXXXX                     0x104d1a63c _hidden#14520_ + 71 (__hidden#14570_:71)
1  XXXXXXXXXX                     0x104d195a4 _hidden#14511_ (__hidden#14570_)
2  XXXXXXXXXX                     0x104d19b80 _hidden#14512_ (__hidden#1229_)
3  XXXXXXXXXX                     0x104de4594 _hidden#21237_ + 70 (__hidden#27902_:70)
4  XXXXXXXXXX                     0x104de3e54 _hidden#27841_ + 4345593428
5  XXXXXXXXXX                     0x104d7ae20 _hidden#21212_ (__hidden#1229_)
6  XXXXXXXXXX                     0x104ca897c _hidden#5864_ + 122 (__hidden#5883_:122)
7  XXXXXXXXXX                     0x104ca8608 _hidden#5854_ (__hidden#1229_)
8  CoreLocation                   0x1a6066f1c CLClientStopVehicleHeadingUpdates + 72644
9  CoreLocation                   0x1a6066d20 CLClientStopVehicleHeadingUpdates + 72136
10 CoreLocation                   0x1a60503b8 CLClientInvalidate + 1400
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1a2eba614 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1a2eb9db4 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 264
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1a2eb54ec __CFRunLoopRun + 2312
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1a2eb48bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
15 GraphicsServices               0x1acd20328 GSEventRunModal + 104
16 UIKitCore                      0x1a6f4a6d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
17 XXXXXXXXXX                     0x104c70a38 main + 20 (__hidden#1227_:20)
18 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a2d3f460 start + 4
```

When I ask for location permission with

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

my app crashes. System dialog for asking location permissions is not shown, only screen is faded and after 3 second app crashes. On 99% devices it is working without problems only on one device it is crashing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you provide de symbolicated crash log

Comment: This is crashlog from Crashlytics. There is also uploaded dsym file so I don't know why is there not more info.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem was that new iOS 13 screen recording is **NOT** recording location permission dialog. So in reality, location permission dialog was shown, user tapped "only once" and than app crashes... OMG, took 2 weeks to realize this

Comment: Hey were you able to fix the crash?

Comment: Yes, problem was developer mistake. He forget to add strings in one language and app crashed on force cast in code...